# DBUtil - Return error code, msg or throw exception

Tags: java, exception

I have a DBUtil class for jdbc,  some method like query, insert and update, when   some errors occur, we throw a RuntimeException now, but I have some questions.
 When error occor, if I don't use try catch block to handle exception, I can't define whether it was succeed or not in code, so I can't do other things using the result, and controller will have no response rather than 500 error.

1:

```
try{

} catch(Exception e){
    throw new RuntimeException("...")
}
```

2:

```
try{

} catch(Exception e){
    log.error("..")
    return someresult;// -1, empty list or others
}
```

so, which is better in code?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the answer is `depends`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any system not handling exceptions is not a good idea.

If you want centralized exception handling then
you can throw exceptions from multiple parts of application and handle in centralized class/controller
 in such cases you can use

```
try{
} catch(Exception e){
    throw new RuntimeException("...")
}
```

in catch you can have custom exception classes with proper message and all

If you want handle exceptions right away then you can try

```
    try{

} catch(Exception e){
    log.error("..")
    return someresult;// -1, empty list or others
}
```

for e.g. if exception comes in try block you will be returning false otherwise true. Or null or blank message depends on implementation.

when you are re-throwing exception you can use finally to close resultsets/ open stream etc which is good practise

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create a custom exception class for your application. 
Handle all your exception in one custom class. And handling method inside this class for all the exceptions occurred.

```
class CustomExc extends Exception{  
 CustomExc(String s){  
  super(s);  
 }  
}
```